# React: Change children of parent by child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

We want to change the content of the parent by a child. Is there any other possibility than clone every child an add the change methods to props?
For example there could be some more children and we get performance issues. We are also able to use react-redux. But since saving a whole component into the store is an anti-pattern, there is only this solution?

In the following is an example by using `React.cloneElement`.

Parent

```
 export default class Parent extends PureComponent {
  static propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.any
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const content = React.Children.map(this.props.children, child =>
      React.cloneElement(child, {
        restoreContent: this.restoreContent.bind(this),
        setContent: this.setContent.bind(this)
      }));

    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      content
    });
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const content = React.Children.map(nextProps.children, child =>
      React.cloneElement(child, {
        restoreContent: this.restoreContent.bind(this),
        setContent: this.setContent.bind(this)
      }));

    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      content
    });
  }

  setContent(content) {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      content,
      storedContent: this.state.content
    });
  }

  restoreContent() {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      content: this.state.storedContent,
      storedContent: null
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.state.content}</div>;
  }
}
```

Child

```
export default class Child extends PureComponent {
  static propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.any,
    restoreContent: PropTypes.func,
    setContent: PropTypes.func
  };

  render() {
    const content = (
      <div>
        <div>Changed-Content</div>
        <button onClick={ () => this.props.restoreContent() }></button>
      </div>

      );

    return (
      <div>Default-Child-Content</div>
      <button onClick={() => this.props.setContent(content)}>Change</button>
    );
  }
}
```

Main

```
<Parent>
  <Child />
</Parent>
```

UseCase example:
You want to simulate a mobilescreen with a meatballmenu. Clicking on the meatballmenu, shows a fullscreen list of options inside the mobilescreen.

```css
.background {
  background: green;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
 }
 
 .mobileScreen {
  width: 40%;
  height: 80%;
  background: blue;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="background">
    <div class="mobileScreen">
      <div>Default-content</div>
      <button>Change Content</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to solve a problem that shouldn't exist in the first place. What is the problem you noticed that made you implement this cloning stuff? And what exactly does `change the content of the parent by a child` mean? Make sure you're asking about your *problem*, not your attempted solution.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.I added a usecase example to the question. The problem/question is, if there is any better solution to solve the given problem.

Comment: It sounds like all you want to do is send some message from a child to its parent. Why would this require you to clone children? I still don't understand what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Yes you are right. I want to send some messages from a child to a parent. The only way I know, is to give the child a "change function" of the parent?

Comment: Yes, without using Redux or Flow or whatever, that's the basic pattern (although the latest React version introduces contexts). However that still doesn't explain why you think you have to clone the children? If you change a parent's state, and its children are rendered based on the state, React will automatically update everything. Just make sure that array elements have a unique `key` property. Again, I think you're trying to solve a problem that doesn't actually exist.